# how to write dice rolling game project. this is my first project

Tags: python

did i write correct code

```
no1 = 1
no2 = 6
enter code here
dice = input("enter number: "):
no1 = int(input("enter number one: "))
no2 = int(input("enter number two: "))
    print("you have enter "+str(no1))
    print("you have enter "+str(no2))

if dice == "5":
    print("you want to roll again")
elif dice == "6":
    print("roll dice automatically")
```

check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code

Comment: What is the goal of you game ? Is there any problem playing it ? Pleaes explain us and give details

Comment: We have no idea if this code is correct, because you didn't explain what it is _supposed_ to do.

Comment: I don't see any actual dice being rolled here, just some inputs and prints...

Comment: @azro im just confuse what to use. like when to use what. like if you tell me to go to one city to another city. you tell me to write code. but thats what i dont know how to write. i know all the codes but just dont know which method to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to write a dice rolling program. However, the simplest way would use a built-in library called random. Below I have fixed and cleaned the code:

```
import random # The libary used from generating random numbers

def dice_roll(): # function usedto reset the game
  input("Press enter to roll the dice ") 
  print("The dice rolled: ", random.randint(0,6)) 

  UserInputNew = input ("Would you like to roll again? ") 

  if UserInputNew == "5": 
    print("\n") # displays a blank line
    dice_roll()
  else:
    print ("Thanks for playing!")

dice_roll() # loads the game
```

Above would do what you want. From your example above, you have loads of inputs which doesn't make sense from something like a dice roll. If you need help understanding certain bits of the code then I'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: thank you Linda. How long you been coding. I'm completely new so hardest part for me is what to use and when to use like import, def, input,if-else.

Comment: Anytime @brijeshP. I have been coding for a couple of years in Python, C# etc. When I first started learning to program I learned the basic foundations first such as stuff like functions, iteration (while loops, for loops) and conditional statements like IF statements for example. When I learned them I then tried to see how I'll be able to apply them in the real world. Soon as you get the foundations, learning other languages is much easier. Also, practice makes perfect so it's important to never give up. Anyways, the best of luck and if you need any help I'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: i think i know the basic. i just not getting how to do project. do you have email or any other way i can contact you.

Answer (score 0):

help on this one
Alice, Bob and Carol have agreed to pool their Halloween candy and split it evenly among themselves. For the sake of their friendship, any candies left over will be smashed. For example, if they collectively bring home 91 candies, they'll take 30 each and smash 1.

Write an arithmetic expression below to calculate how many candies they must smash for a given haul.